# transmission-remote / transmission-remote-gtk : gtk client throwing 405 error

Tags: transmission

Using a web browser I can access the torrent client running on a VM at 192.168.56.1:9091 -- the VirtualBox host-only IP address.

Using torrent-remote-gtk, from the same host,using the same connection parameters I get a http error 405.

Since the IP is whitelisted I don't understand why the gtk version is failing.

```
 transmission-remote-gtk 1.5.1-1
 transmission-* 4.0.3-1
 6.3.1-arch1-1
```